# Sending email through Gmail SMTP using PHP

Tags: php

I have following system setup

- Windows XP Service pack 2
- WAMP 2.0
- PHP 5.3

I've configured my `php.ini` file with the following:

```
smtp=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=25;
```

and my PHP code is

```
<?php
    mail('alagar.pandi@gmail.com','test subject','test body');
?>
```

The error I'm getting is

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 
530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. 
4sm389277yxd.16 in C:\wamp\www\limosbusesjets\test.php on line 5
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

I have always used [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=phpmailer) for all my mailing needs.
It has built in support for GMail as a server (and it's free)

I think your issue is that you are trying to use PHP's mail settings and not PHPMailer's
Make sure you have the following set:

```
$mail               = new PHPMailer();  //Setup the mailer
$mail->IsSMTP();
//$mail->SMTPDebug      = 2;
$mail->SMTPAuth     = true;                     //enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure   = "ssl";                    //sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host         = "smtp.gmail.com";         //sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port         = 465;                      //set the SMTP port
$mail->Username     = $guser;       //GMAIL username
$mail->Password     = $gpwd;                //GMAIL password
$mail->AddReplyTo($fromAddress,$fromName);
$mail->From         = $guser;
$mail->FromName     = "Your name";  
$mail->Subject      = $subject;     //E-Mail subject
$mail->AltBody      = $bodyAlt;         //Text Body
$mail->WordWrap     = 50;              //set word wrap
$mail->Priority = $priority;          //Mail priority
$mail->MsgHTML($ebody);
```

Comment: i was used that but it shows following error
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate

Comment: Check out my edit...and SMTP on gmail is not port 25, it's 465.  Take a look at docs/use_gmail.txt in the PHPMailer directory

Comment: thx, that helped me a lot! Should be the accepted answer for that question!

Answer (score 3):

Mail via Google needs to be run through SSL.

There are a lot of arcticles on subject, you might find this useful: http://deepakssn.blogspot.com/2006/06/gmail-php-send-email-using-php-with.html