# Sending email through smtp server

Tags: php, smtp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending email through Gmail SMTP using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881409/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-using-php)

Hi,

I am working on a site, that uses mail() function of php to send emails. However the emails are not delivered properly as the server has got some problems. I want to use gmail server to send emails for this reason. How can i implement the php script to send emails using smtp server authentication? Also i have learnt that it uses pear package for email to send emails. How can I know that pear is installed on my remote server. The server doenot allow me to view php info()? Please help...

Comment: Getting error as 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PEAR_Error::send() in /home/fpark/public_html/emailtest.php on line 25

Answer (score 1):

[Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page)

I think it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Pear Mail](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.php) with SMTP is very easy, and you can see some examples

```
$_mailbox        =   Mail::factory('smtp', array( 
  'host'         => 'smtp.gmail.com', 
  'auth'         =>  FALSE, 
  'username'     => 'username@gmail.com', 
  'password'     => 'smtp_password', 
  'persist'      =>  FALSE  ));
```

Sorry i don'r read all question, you can't know if you have pear in server, why not send email or ticket to support ?

Answer (score 0):

[PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) is a very good PHP library to send e-mails. You may just install the files into your own area, no administrator action is necessary.